# mount an unmountable drive

Tags: macos, mount, root

I have a MacBook Pro with a root mounting sector with problems. It becomes like this due to password changing in safe mode.
Now of course it doesn't turn up any more.
I tried repair with disk utility
I tried CMD+R using terminal
I tried several reparing softwares to save data

All without any success.
Any idea at least how to save data?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use testdisk. (Freeware, http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)

I've once had a disk that could not be read by the system nor anything. I just ran testdisk and was able to recover all of the data on the disk.

Comment: After trying more than 10 different software. I did it, unfortunately I didn't find your software. I want to thank you anyway. I used data rescue and I saved everything.